# Multi-threaded fule upload with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, file-transfer, youtube, upload

I have 100 mbit GPON internet connection with about 80 mbit upload speed. When I try to upload video on youtube with Mozilla 42, it uploads with 4-5 mbits. In chrome, uploading stars with same speed but then increases to 25-27. I guess this is because of it has some kind of multi threaded upload system? It there a way to increase the amount of threads so I can upload files faster?